# Refreshing the form after cancellation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

In my windows form i have added a button to enter new record , and when that selected , the button text changes as cancel and the focus will move to first entry field .
But if i click  cancel without entering any data , the focus is not getting removed .and when i press next record then the focus is removed & i can press add new record button again.
Kindly help me how to solve this .below is my code

```
    Private Sub AddnewButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddnewButton.Click
    'MsgBox("you preseed add new button")
    Try
        With AddnewButton
            If .Text = "Add New Record" Then
                MSdiesBindingSource.AddNew()
                .Text = "Cancel"
            Else
                RefreshData()
                .Text = "Add New Record"
            End If

        End With
        With Size_in_mgTextBox
            If (.CanSelect) Then
                .Text = String.Empty
                .Select()
            End If
        End With

        IsAddNewRecordInProgress = Convert.ToBoolean(AddnewButton.Text = "Cancel")


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occured: " & ex.Message.ToString().ToString(),
              MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add new Record Failed")
    End Try
End Sub
    Private Sub RefreshData()
    Try
        'Me.MSdiesBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
        MSdiesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TrialdatabaseDataSet.MSdies)
        MSdiesBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Refresh Data Error!")
    End Try


End Sub
```

[image: Trialdatabasedataset]

```
SELECT        ID, [Size in mg], [Die head number], [Inspection Date], [Next Calibration Date], [Die size in microns],[Condition of DIE-1], [Condition of DIE-2], [Condition of DIE-3], [Condition of DIE-4], [Condition of DIE-5],[Condition of DIE-6],[Condition of DIE-7], Observations, Inspector
```

FROM            MSdies

[image: MSdies table details]

Comment: When you click the Cancel button, you can use [`BindingSource.RemoveCurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.removecurrent?view=netcore-3.1) and maybe `AddnewButton.Focus()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but after adding msdiesBindingSource.RemoveCurrent , the record is getting deleted and focus is till nor refreshing.Could you please modify my code on how i could incorporate this?

Comment: I suppose you are using a datagridview on your form. Have you tried `datagridview.ClearSelection` ?

Comment: This is clearing the selection in data grid box , but still the complete refresh is not occurring.(means still the ficus present on 2nd field entry blocking to press again add new record),Basically what i want is when i press [add new record] button , the form goes to edit mode , but when i hit the same button (which is now showing as cancel) it should reset to the edit mode(complete refresh)

Comment: Could you provide more details about your 'MSdiesTableAdapter', 'TrialdatabaseDataSet' and 'MSdiesBindingSource' ? It will help others to reproduce your problem and make a test.

Comment: Hi  @XingyuZhao the question is updated with 2 images and sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
But if i click cancel without entering any data , the focus is not getting removed
```

In order to remove the focus from 'Size_in_mgTextBox', You can make some changes to your code:

```
    With Size_in_mgTextBox
        If (.CanSelect) Then
            .Select()
        End If
    End With
    With AddnewButton
        If .Text = "Add New Record" Then
            bindingSource.AddNew()
            .Text = "Cancel"
        Else
            RefreshData()
            .Text = "Add New Record"
        End If
    End With

    Size_in_mgTextBox.Text = String.Empty
```

Then add the following code to the 'RefreshData' method: `Me.ActiveControl = Nothing`

```
Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Size_in_mgTextBox.Text.Trim = "" Then
        Me.ActiveControl = Nothing
    Else
        '...
    End If
End Sub
```